# What's the best way in Postgres to store a bunch of arbitrary boolean values for a row?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a database full of recipes, one recipe per row.  I need to store a bunch of arbitrary "flags" for each recipe to mark various properties such as Gluton-Free, No meat, No Red Meat, No Pork, No Animals, Quick, Easy, Low Fat, Low Sugar, Low Calorie, Low Sodium and Low Carb.  Users need to be able to search for recipes that contain one or more of those flags by checking checkboxes in the UI.

I'm searching for the best way to store these properties in the Recipes table.  My ideas so far:

1. Have a separate column for each property and create an index on each of those columns.  I may have upwards of about 20 of these properties, so I'm wondering if there's any drawbacks with creating a whole bunch of BOOL columns on a single table.
2. Use a bitmask for all properties and store the whole thing in one numeric column that contains the appropriate number of bits.  Create a separate index on each bit so searches will be fast.
3. Create an ENUM with a value for each tag, then create a column that has an ARRAY of that ENUM type.  I believe an ANY clause on an array column can use an INDEX, but have never done this.
4. Create a separate table that has a one-to-many mapping of recipes to tags.  Each tag would be a row in this table.  The table would contain a link to the recipe, and an ENUM value for which tag is "on" for that recipe.  When querying, I'd have to do a nested SELECT to filter out recipes that didn't contain at least one of these tags.  I think this is the more "normal" way of doing this, but it does make certain queries more complicated - If I want to query for 100 recipes and also display all their tags, I'd have to use an INNER JOIN and consolidate the rows, or use a nested SELECT and aggregate on the fly.

Write performance is not too big of an issue here since recipes are added by a backend process, and search speed is critical (there might be a few hundred thousand recipes eventually).  I doubt I will add new tags all that often, but I want it to be at least possible to do without major headaches.

Thanks!

Comment: HSTORE and JSONB column types are worth considering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise you to use a normalized setup. Setting this up from the get go as a de-normalized structure is not what I would advise.

Without knowing all the details of what he have going on I think the best setup would be to have your recipe table and new property table and a new recipe_property table. That allows a recipe to have 0 or many properties and normalizes your data making it fast and easy to maintain and query your data.

High level structure would be:

```
CREATE TABLE recipe(recipe_id);
CREATE TABLE property(property_id);
CREATE TABLE recipe_property(recipe_property_id,recipe_id,property_id);
```

Comment: Yup that's definitely one route.  I'm also thinking about using an `ENUM` instead of `property_id`, and not having a `property` table.  Though, internally in the database it's the same thing as what you have.

Comment: Just make sure your final solution doesn't paint you into a corner.

Comment: I ended up going the normalized route after getting the same advice from many experts.  However, I did briefly look into the `hstore` module for Postgres, which is pretty sweet; however I elected not to use it for this particular situation.

Comment: I have found in general that the more straight forward a solution the better it is, and I'm not talking about using the duct tape approach.  I have been victimized countless times in my life with messes where code was written in an overly clever manner.  In return you have to over think just to get a clue of what is going on. When you have to maintain that type stuff it makes you want to switch careers.